# how to fix the syntax error i getting in react component?

Tags: reactjs

I work by a tutorial to create a fullstack react web app with backend connected to mongo , now while trying to merge it with my previous code I getting a syntax error..

i try to search in google but none of it help

this is my console error

```
module build failed(from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js);
syntaxError: c:/users/aviram/zofim/client/src/app.js: unexpected token (49:16)

49| getDataFromDb = () => {
```

this is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


class App extends Component {
  // initialize our state
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      id: 0,
      message: null,
      intervalIsSet: false,
      idToDelete: null,
      idToUpdate: null,
      objectToUpdate: null
    };
    this.getDataFromDb = this.getDataFromDb.bind(this);
  }

  // when component mounts, first thing it does is fetch all existing data in our db
  // then we incorporate a polling logic so that we can easily see if our db has
  // changed and implement those changes into our UI
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataFromDb();
    if (!this.state.intervalIsSet) {
      let interval = setInterval(this.getDataFromDb, 1000);
      this.setState({ intervalIsSet: interval });
    }
  }

  // never let a process live forever
  // always kill a process everytime we are done using it
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.state.intervalIsSet) {
      clearInterval(this.state.intervalIsSet);
      this.setState({ intervalIsSet: null });
    }
  }
  // just a note, here, in the front end, we use the id key of our data object
  // in order to identify which we want to Update or delete.
  // for our back end, we use the object id assigned by MongoDB to modify
  // data base entries
  // our first get method that uses our backend api to
  // fetch data from our data base
  getDataFromDb = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/getData')
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((res) => this.setState({ data: res.data }));
};
```

I`d like it to compile

Comment: Depends how you've set up your build pipeline, post relevant babel config. In short use this https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem change this line `getDataFromDb = () => {` to `getDataFromDb(){`.

This is happening because you don't have class properties configured on your build configurations, a plugin for babel: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Note that this syntax `getDataFromDb = () => {` is not approved yet, the proposal and more info on class properties: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields

Comment: thank you , now its :
`
] ERROR in ./src/app.js
[1] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
[1] SyntaxError: C:/Users/aviram/zofim/client/src/app.js: Unexpected token (108:6)
[1]
[1]   106 |     const { data } = this.state;
[1]   107 |     return (
[1] > 108 |       <div>
[1]       |       ^
[1]   109 |         <ul>
[1]   110 |           {data.length <= 0
[1]   111 |             ? 'NO DB ENTRIES YET'
[1]
`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is here,

```
 let interval = setInterval(this.getDataFromDb, 1000);
```

You should call your `getDataFromDb` function like this,

```
let interval = setInterval(this.getDataFromDb(), 1000);
```

Also as you are using arrow function, no need to bind `this`,

```
this.getDataFromDb = this.getDataFromDb.bind(this); //You can remove this line
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-r8y1o?fontsize=14).

**Note:: Here fetch call changed to some other URL to get it work.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using arrow function then there is no need to bind. So remove `this.getDataFromDb = this.getDataFromDb.bind(this);` this line it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to complete closing bracket } at the end. If you are using arrow function then there is no need of bind so remove this line 'this.getDataFromDb = this.getDataFromDb.bind(this);'